# Return the older element (DateTime) in array

Tags: php

I have an array of `Cars` Objects and I need return the **older** (hours, minutes, seconds are include in calc) car to user, How I can do it?

**Car class**

```
class Carr { 
    public $brand
    public $model
    public $color;
    public $realeasedDate; //DateTime like: 2015-01-01 23:59:59 in BD is store as 1983-01-01T00:00:00+0000
}
```

Comment: You need to do this when fetching your information from your database using SQL `MAX` on the date columns.

Comment: Is `$releasedDate` instance of `DateTime` class?

Comment: @felipsmartins correct, $releasedDate is instance of DateTime

Comment: @Ricardo Nice! Also, Why have you been not sorting when fetching database data?

Comment: @felipsmartins now I'm using the database sort

Comment: @Ricardo Well... So it's supposed you should close this question?

Comment: @felipsmartins no because the sort with database isn't ideal solution.

Comment: @Ricardo Why not? It strikes me it is the best solution in matter of performance and simplicity.

Comment: @felipsmartins correct but the database sort , sort only on ASC and DESC, In my mind the usort is best solution at this moment

Comment: @Ricardo - "Sort with database isn't an ideal solution"? **What?**  It's absolutely the ideal solution.  DBs are designed to do exactly that kind of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this should do it, (untested)

```
private static function sortByRealeasedDate($car1, $car2)
    {
        if ($car1->releasedDate === $car2->releasedDate) {
            return 0;
        }
        return strtotime($car1->releasedDate) > strtotime($car2->releasedDate) ? -1 : 1;
    }

usort($carsArray, 'sortByRealeasedDate'));
```

Comment: throw this warining: usort() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback, function 'sortByRealeasedDate' not found or invalid function name

Comment: instead of private static function sortByReleasedDate() just use function sortByReleasedDate(), in the same file as your call to it.   Sorry, I kind of copied a working function of mine from a PHP object

Answer (score 3):

Use [`usort`](http://php.net/usort) to sort the array using a user-defined comparison function.  Then pick the final element.